# How do I create a superuser account in Django 1.9.6

Tags: python, django, web-deployment

I am reading a book ("Learning Django Web Development" by Sanjeev Jaiswal and Ratan Kumar) on Django, but the book is based on an earlier version of Django (prior to version 1.9).  In order to populate the database with tables, the book uses the syncdb command:

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
```

Then the book says that terminal will prompt you to create a superuser account.

the syncdb command is no longer used in Django version 1.9 and up.  After some research, it seems as if the migrate command populates the databse with tables, but it does not prompt the creation of a superuser account. How can I do this in Django 1.9.6?

Answer (score 52):

I think you want to run these commands:

`python manage.py makemigrations` creates migration files based on your models

`python manage.py migrate` will create the tables in your db based on the migration files created

(see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/) for more details on database migrations)

`python manage.py createsuperuser` will create a superuser for your application in the database ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser))

Comment: Thanks! However, the book also says the settings.py file should look like:             # Django settings for django_mytweets project.
   DEBUG = True
   TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
   ADMINS = (
       # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
   )
    MANAGERS = ADMINS
   DATABASE_ENGINE = ''
   DATABASE_NAME = '' ..... (more lines as well).  After creating the super user, this didnt happen.. Do you have any idea as to how to get similar results?

Comment: the `ADMINS = ` setting is just a list of people who will will get error notifications ([see here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#admins)), not a list of superusers

Comment: You have to fill the settings.py file out yourself, it's not dynamically generated, so I would not expect any change there after creating the super user (if that's what you meant by "this didn't happen")

Comment: Oh. Ok.  The wording in the book is: "OK, now that you have a source code editor ready, let's open settings.py in the project folder and see what it contains".  It never prompted me to edit the settings.py, so I was confused as to why there was no change.  Thanks!

Comment: There is `User.objects.create_user()` in the `ipython`-shell. Would a `create_superuser()` make sense? I use `cygwin` have not `python manage.py createsuperuser`

Answer (score 14):

```
$ python manage.py migrate
$ python manage.py createsuperuser
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/

Answer (score 4):

For Django 2

```
User.objects.create_superuser(username='name',email='email',password='password')
```

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User)

> create_superuser(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
>
> Same as create_user(), but sets is_staff and is_superuser to True.

Which can be embedded in a script, called from a command line or triggered via an API

Comment: Or use django.core.management.call_command(name, *args, **options) see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#django.core.management.call_command

Answer (score 3):

first run

```
$ django-admin startproject mysite
```

in cmd prompt,then apply migration by

```
cd mysite
```

mysite:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

then

```
python manage.py migrate
```

after that

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you make sure your answer is properly formatted? Here's a link about [How to format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 3):

First we’ll need to create a user who can login to the admin site. Run
 the following command:

```
$ python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Enter your desired username and press enter. Username: admin

You will then be prompted for your desired email address:

```
Email address: admin@example.com
```

The final step is to enter your password. You will be asked to enter
 your password twice, the second time as a confirmation of the first.

```
Password: **********
Password (again): *********
Superuser created successfully.
```

Answer (score 1):

$ python manage.py createsuperuser

It will ask username and password

http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
see

https://www.tutorialshore.com/create-new-admin-user-in-django/

Answer (score 0):

you create superuser with this :

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

this will create superuser for you and you can create many superuser .
but notice before you can make super user you must run these command :

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and them :

```
python manage.py migrate
```