# After installing Django CMS, system asks for admin credentials

Tags: django-cms

I'm trying to use Django CMS for a website project. I've installed it from my virtual environment by entering the following command: `pip install djangocms-installer`
Things seemingly went well.
After that I created a new project on my desktop by typing: `djangocms -p communimmo communimmo`
It was created successfully.
The last lines in my command prompt showed:

```
Creating admin user
All done!
Get into "MyProjectPath" directory and type "python manage.py runserver" to start your project
```

But after running `python manage.py runserver`, the webpage on my local server asks me for Django Administration credentials. At no point during the installation I was asked to set up an admin user, so basically I'm stuck.

Did I miss a step somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a superuser account in Django 1.9.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618059/how-do-i-create-a-superuser-account-in-django-1-9-6)

Comment: I thought it would link to the specific answer but it did not. You are looking for `python manage.py createsuperuser` from the command prompt

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work!

Comment: I have this same question - of course you can create a *new* superuser, but I still have no idea how to login with the admin django-cms created for me...

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/01-install.html#use-the-django-cms-installer.

> The installer creates an admin user for you, with username/password admin/admin.